# How to fix "UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found" error using jni and javah

Tags: c++, android-studio, java-native-interface, javah

I want to use C++ method inside my Java code. So I decided to use JNI. But the link seams to not work properly, du to my error at the execution `No implementation found for void com.me.Native.helloWorld() (tried Java_com_me_Native_helloWorld and Java_com_me_Native_helloWorld__)`

**Native.java** (called elsewhere as `Native.helloWorld()`):

```
package com.me;
public class Native{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("detection_based_tracker");
    }
    public static native void helloWorld();
}
```

**Android.mk** :

```
...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += com_me_Native.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**com_me_Native.h** (generated with javah command):

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_me_Native */

#ifndef _Included_com_me_Native
#define _Included_com_me_Native
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_me_Native
 * Method:    helloWorld
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_me_Native_helloWorld
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**com_me_Native.cpp** :

```
#include <com_me_Native.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <android/log.h>

#define LOG_TAG "HelloWorld"
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    using namespace std;
    /*
     * Class:     com_me_Native
     * Method:    helloWorld
     * Signature: ()V
     */
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_me_Native_helloWorld
      (JNIEnv *, jclass)
    {
      LOGD("Hello from c++");
    }

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

As you see a use `JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL` on my method. I also use `extern "C"` for C++ use. My `.h` was generated by `javah`. I checked the `Android.mk` and I didn't forgot to add my `.cpp` file to `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`. I statically loaded my library in the `Native.java` to use my static function.

Now I don't know where the error may come from... Any idea ?!

Comment: By the way, you should be using the functions from `android/log.h`, not `printf` or `puts` or `std::cout`.

Comment: Absolutely, code updated !

Answer (score 0):

The include guard should only be in the `.h` file, not in the `.cpp` file.

So in your `.cpp` file, remove these lines:

```
#ifndef _Included_com_me_Native
#define _Included_com_me_Native
```

As well as the final `#endif`.

What happens with your curent code is that `_Included_com_me_Native` gets defined when you include your header file, so then the `#ifndef _Included_com_me_Native` in the `.cpp` file will be false, and none of that code gets compiled.

Comment: I removed those lines, but the error remain the same. (code in question updated)

Comment: Are you positive that the `.so` file has been bundled with your APK (for some ABI matching the device you're running this on)?

Comment: The `.so` file is in `arm64-v8a` folder. how to know if my phone match to it ?
You have to know that in the same `.so` there is an other `.cpp` with functions that works well.

Comment: Well, I'm unable to reproduce the issue. The function is found just fine when I try it. Though Android Studio didn't like the `#include <com_me_Native.h>` so I changed it to `#include "com_me_Native.h"`.

Comment: I also tried this, but nothing change: same error. It's still mysterious to me.

Comment: I changed `detection_based_tracker` to `Me_Native` in `CMakeLists.txt` , `Android.mk` and in java `System.loadLibrary("Me_Native");`. Now I have no errors but nothing is printed in the console..